# connecting to host running ssh2 server using ssh client

Tags: linux, ssh, openssh, sshd

I am trying to connect to a linux host( target_host) running sshd2 using a ssh client( client_host) ;While doing so I converted the pub key of client_host as

```
ssh-keygen -e -f id_rsa.pub > client_host_ssh2_id_rsa.pub
```

and copied client_host_ssh2_id_rsa.pub to target_host. However when i try to connect I get "no hostkey alg"

```
ssh user@target_host -v
OpenSSH_5.1p1, OpenSSL 0.9.8a 11 Oct 2005
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: Connecting to target [169.35.74.21] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/identity type -1
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_dsa type 2
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version 6.0.12.81   SSH  Tectia Server
debug1: no match: 6.0.12.81 SSH Tectia Server
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
 debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.1
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-cbc hmac-md5 none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-cbc hmac-md5 none
no hostkey alg
```

Can someone please help me identify what am I missing here.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely, what you are missing is, on the remote machine:

```
 cd $HOME/.ssh;  cat client_host_ssh2_id_rsa.pub >> authorized_keys
```

If this is not enough, then stop the sshd daemon, then restart it as follows:

```
 /usr/sbin/sshd -Dd
```

which prevents daemonization, and prints error message to standard output. As you try to log in, in this way you will be able to see the error messages on the server side, which are much more informative than those on the client side, for obvious security reasons. This will help you/us to debug the problem.